# Appcelerator Studio indexes very slow

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio, appcelerator-hyperloop

Once in a while Appcelerator Studio starting task "Building workspace... " and it shows that it indexes "/iphone/hyperloop/..." or "/android/hyperloop/..." even though I've disabled hyperloop in my project. Does anyone know how can I get rid of this long indexing? It takes like 20 minutes and makes no sense to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appcelerator Studio is dog slow and I suggest to use another editor. The editor is Eclipse-based I believe, but as long as it exists it has had performance issues. The build options that are built into the appc studio can be called using the command line (`appc ti build ...`).

Comment: its sad I get a -1 for saying the obvious. Dont use appcelerator studio, it will worsen your development experience unless you badly need some of its "features"

Comment: as a big Atom and CLI user I understand your answer and I would also suggest using a different editor + CLI to get more performance. But the question was not about using a different editor, so I guess the answer is just not correct in that case.

Comment: seems to me that the answer is not the preferred one. Why not give a straight answer instead that actually results in an overall better situation. I think a "do not use" is permitted here. I couldve answered with a solution for this one indexing problem but you will encounter many more performance issues throughout your appcelerator studio experience, which would all require a stack overflow question to either solve or explain.

Comment: I would be happy to use another IDE, but e.g. how can I launch app on ios simulator? build to device? see error log from device?

Comment: For Atom you can use this package: https://atom.io/packages/appcelerator-titanium

Comment: That's fantastic! Much faster and convenient. Thank you!

Comment: when you call `appc ti build` for whichever platform, you get your console feedback as usual. Also you can see some device error logs in the iOS simulator itself (somewhere in the taskbar in the simulator program). The `appc ti build` commando also takes parameters for building for device/simulator/emulator

Answer (score 2):

Exclude these folders from the project tree by adding [Resource filters](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/resourcefilters.htm). Add **Exclude All** resource filter type to root folder of your project. You can also use regular expressions if needed.

This will avoid indexing the excluded files and folders, hence it will improve the performance.

**Steps:**

1. Right click on the project
2. Click on the project
3. Go to Resources -> Resources Filter
4. Click on Add Filter...
5. Select "Exclude All" from the Filter Type section
6. Select "Folders" from the Applies to section
7. Enter "**modules**" in the textbox as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the automatic build under "Preferneces - General - Workspace - Build automatically" or inside the Project menu disable "Build automatically". If you still have the problem you could file a ticket at https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Tried your method - unfortunately it doesn't work. When I run application it still sometimes starts to index /hyperloop/ ... files which takes unreasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all the previous module versions of hyperloop and facebook.

Go to:

```
Library>Application Support>Titanium>modules
```

Look in:

```
iphone>hyperloop
iphone>facebook
android>hyperloop
android>facebook
```

I deleted all previous modules in those folders, keeping only the latest.